# Django REST framework APIView and atomic transactions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, atomic

I have several of django REST framework's APIView each with different requests (get, put, post and delete). I need to make atomic transactions tied to the HTTP requests associated with the views, but the issue is that unless an exception is thrown from the view, django things that the request was executed successfully.

However, I am catching my errors internally and returning 400 codes inside a Response object when an error was encountered. Is there any way to make the rollback mechanism happen when a non 200 code is returned, rather than when an exception is caught?

Comment: Within the Django Rest Framework, there is a default mechanism to return 400 upon unhandled exceptions. Why not letting the framework do this job, and then your transactions will rollback because of the exception? The handling of the exceptions are done in the request-response dispatch mechanism, where the transaction is being set up.

Comment: If you need to perform handling of the exceptions yourself, do forward the exception by re-raise them again.